# Usar status code 422 para exceções do tipo InvalidArgumentException

Tags: php, exceção

Segundo a documentação do PHP a exceção [`InvalidArgumentException`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.invalidargumentexception.php) deve ser utilizada quando um argumento não esperado pela aplicação é recebido.

Segundo status code [400](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) e [422](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422) no site do developer.mozila, diz:

> 400: O código de status de resposta HTTP 400 Bad Request indica que o servidor não pode ou não irá processar a requisição devido a alguma coisa que foi entendida como um erro do cliente (por exemplo, sintaxe de requisição mal formada, enquadramento de mensagem de requisição inválida ou requisição de roteamento enganosa).
>
> 422: O codigo de resposta HTTP 422 *Unprocessable Entity* indica que o servidor entende o tipo de conteúdo da entidade da requisição, e a sintaxe da requisição esta correta, mas não foi possível processar as instruções presentes.

Qual `status code` seria correto utilizar numa exceção do tipo `InvalidArgumentException`?

```
if (is_null($attribute)) {
    $message = sprintf('The attribute %s can not be null', $attribute);
    throw new InvalidArgumentException($message, 400);
} 


if (is_null($attribute)) {
    $message = sprintf('The attribute %s can not be null', $attribute);
    throw new InvalidArgumentException($message, 422);
}
```

Ou existe outro `status code` mais apropriado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A classe de `status code` 4xx destina-se a situações nas quais **o erro parece ter sido causado pelo cliente**. Isto é, usar o `status code` 400 ou 422 de uma forma geral a aplicação estará repassando o entendimento ao cliente que o erro está do lado dele e ele precisa arrumá-lo caso queiro realizar uma nova comunicação.

Logo, o que vai decidir se o correto seria utilizar um ou outro será a nomenclatura adotada para desenvolver a aplicação. Eu quero explicar que, ambas estão certas, e se você trabalha com várias pessoas em uma ou mais aplicações decidiram adotar como padrão aplicar o `status code 422` para exceções do tipo `InvalidArgumentException` o contexto não mudará para o cliente. O erro continua sendo do lado dele.

Dá uma olhada neste [link](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2434-http-status-codes-for-invalid-data-400-vs-422.htm). Segundo o autor, recomenda-se utilizar `status code 422` para exceções do tipo `InvalidArgumentException`.